# How do I display pdf in new tab?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, pdf

I would like to add data to a pdf from my controller then display in a new tab.

I have the following in my Model which works:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    PdfStamper formFiller = new PdfStamper(reader, ms);
    AcroFields formFields = formFiller.AcroFields;
    formFields.SetField("First", first);

    formFiller.FormFlattening = true;
    formFiller.Writer.CloseStream = false;
    formFiller.Close();
 }
```

I had this send a attached pdf email which works, but I would like to make the edits and open in a new tab. How do I do that?

Comment: that action was from some menu or link no? why not on that link add `target="_blank"` or add a new link saying "Download PDF"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have the link open in a _blank.  Wouldn't that work?  You would need to correlate the request in that new tab with the edits in the original window.

Comment: I was over thinking the problem. Thanks for bringing me back to earth :)